# Authenticate Jenkins remotely

Tags: authentication, jenkins

I have Jenkin's running on my PC, and I've created a dashboard that pulls in various bits of data from various sources.

The problem I have is that I need to be able to authenticate my JSON request, I've passing inside the JSON request the following;

```
"data": {
      "alt": "json-in-script",
      "userName": "test", "password" : "test"
  }
```

But this doesn't appear to work. How do I authenticate against Jenkins remotely?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to authenticate your HTTP request itself, as opposed to putting the access paramters inside the payload.  See the [Jenkins documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients) for an example.

Comment: Thanks, but thats using Java and I'm using JQuery (my bad for not mentioning that). I need to keep it completely JS